# GUI Builder: display a set of String returned by a query

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, label, builder

I'm creating a very simple interface which allows to select 2 ingredients from 2 combobox, and by clicking a button it makes a query on an ontology.
The query returns an ArrayList of String. 
How can i display all the String of the ArrayList in my interface??
I tried this:

```
JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel();
```

and then:

```
for(int i=0; i<arrayListName.size(); i++){
   jLabel1.setText(arrayListName.get(i));
}
```

It works but it display only the last result of the query. How do I display all the results?

Answer (score 0):

It displays only the last result simply because text is set to specific String from the list during every iteration of for loop. You just need to add every element to Your Jlabel instead of setting the whole text to this element. Try:

```
for(int i=0; i<arrayListName.size(); i++){
     jLabel1.setText(jLabel1.getText() + " " + arrayListName.get(i));
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you very much!! I didn't understand how to add element to the label!!
And there is a way to print every object in a new line?